# VBA Access form: Submit Button to create new record but keep some values in the form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-office

I have a form to enter all necessary data. With the wizard I created a button that saves the data as a new record, but this button clears the form.

I want this button to do exactly that, but keep some of the entered values in the form, because those values will stay the same for a certain amount of records.

Currently my button runs this code generated by the button creation wizard:

```
Private Sub submit_btn_Click()
On Error GoTo submit_btn_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If


submit_btn_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

submit_btn_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume submit_btn_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

When the button is clicked I want to clear all values in the form, except for the date and a group field. Can I easily do this in this code or is there a way to do this via the default value property of these fields?

Comment: Thanks, i´ll try this! If i want to go for the options with the variables, at what point and how do I give the variables their values? Does that work with Dim DateVar As Date (format should be  dd.mm.yyyy) and then DateVar = DateFieldName? At what position would that code go?

Comment: @Shazu ok, I think we got a misunderstanding: I don´t always want the group or the date to be the same, I just want to keep the values from the last entry. In my system I have daily entries which have a date, an account number a group and so on. So you have around 50 entries daily, and then maybe 10 entries of a group. I want my Form to keep the last entered values so that you don´t have to enter them over and over again. Just as long as the values are correct. Sorry if my first question was a bit unclear.

Comment: My idea to achieve that would be that, when you click the button, the values of the DateField and the GroupField get saved as variables. Then all the data is saved as a new record into the database and all the fields are cleared again. After that the DateField and the GroupField should be filled again with the values stored in the variables.

I just have trouble figuring out how to write that, as i find it difficult to find useful descriptions of the VBA syntax.

Comment: ok, seems like I was writing my text while you where posting your comments. I´ll try it out

Comment: ok, I can´t get either of the ways to work. What would be the code to fill a field with the value of a variable?

Comment: I think that the problem with your solution is, that the hidden text fields also get cleared when saving the record. Or would they be unaffected as they are unbound?

Comment: So, I wrote it like this:

Private Sub submit_btn_Click()
On Error GoTo submit_btn_Click_Err

Dim dateholder As Date
Dim groupholder As String
dateholder = Me.entry_date.Value
groupholder = Me.acc_group.Value

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

Me.entry_date.Value = dateholder
Me.acc_group.Value = groupholder

submit_btn_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

submit_btn_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume submit_btn_Click_Exit
    
End Sub

doesn´t work, any idea why?

Comment: can I format code in the comments?

Comment: Is there another way to submit the record? Maybe as an SQL statement?

Comment: This thread basically makes you look insane :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Go to the properties of your form and put the following code in the BeforeUpdate event:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  entry_date.Tag = CLng(entry_date.Value)
  acc_value.Tag = acc_value.Value
End Sub
```

In the Current event of the form, put the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  If Me.NewRecord Then
    entry_date = CDate(entry_date.Tag)
    acc_value = acc_value.Tag
  End If
End Sub
```

That is all you need to do. If you have any questions please let me know

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense. But something seems to be wrong with the syntax. When I copy&paste your code, adapt the control names and hit enter, I get the error message: The expression you entered contains invalid syntax. You may have entered an operand without an operator.

Comment: Hm, the error mentioned above went away when I found that I can use the code builder for those events ;-) But still it does not work.